# identify the adjacent pixels in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, superpixels

Let's assume A be,

```
     1 1 1 1 1 1
     1 2 2 3 3 3
     4 4 2 2 3 3
     4 4 2 2 2 3
     4 4 4 4 3 3
     5 5 5 5 5 5
```

I need to identify all the numbers which are adjacent to a particular intensity value. E.g. the intensities 1, 3, and 4 are adjacent to the intensity value 2.
What is the effective way to do it in Matlab?

I can use the following,

```
   glcm = graycomatrix(A)
```

But if A have a larger number of intensity values e.g. 10000 graycomatrix will not be an efficient method.

Comment: Well, I doubt there will be any efficient method for the case of 10000 values unless you can put some more limitations on it (because of the large number of possible combinations).

Comment: Why is not `2` also returned? There are `2`'s adjacent to some other `2`'s

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a mask with a 2D convolution, select the values according to that mask, and then reduce them to unique values:

```
% // Data:
A = [ 1 1 1 1 1 1
      1 2 2 3 3 3
      4 4 2 2 3 3
      4 4 2 2 2 3
      4 4 4 4 3 3
      5 5 5 5 5 5 ];
value = 2;
adj = [0 1 0; 1 0 1; 0 1 0]; %// define adjacency. [1 1 1;1 0 1;1 1 1] to include diagonals

%// Let's go
mask = conv2(double(A==value), adj, 'same')>0; %// pixels adjacent to those equal to `value`
result = unique(A(mask));
```

In the example, this produces

```
result =
     1
     2
     3
     4
```

Note that the result includes `2` because some pixels with value `2` have adjacent pixels with that value.